# Observable.Publish with rethrow behaviour

Tags: vb.net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a cold Observable that might `OnError` when it is subscribed to. How can i  create a cold Observable, that returns a single element (an object that receives as a dependency the source Observable), or propagates the `OnError` of the source.
Using the `Publish` operator, the `onError` handler it is not called.

```
Private Shared Sub Test()
    Dim source = Observable.Throw(Of Integer)(New Exception)
    ' Dim source = Observable.Range(0, 9)

    Dim obs = source.Publish(Function(published)
                                 Return Observable.
                                        Return(New ObjectThatConsumesXs(published))
                             End Function)

    obs.Subscribe(Sub(a)

                  End Sub,
                  Sub(ex)

                  End Sub,
                  Sub()

                  End Sub)
End Sub


Private Class ObjectThatConsumesXs
    Private _subscription As IDisposable

    Public Sub New(source As IObservable(Of Integer))
        _subscription = source.Subscribe(Sub(x)

                                         End Sub,
                                         Sub(ex)

                                         End Sub,
                                         Sub()

                                         End Sub)
    End Sub
End Class
```

EDIT:

This is going to be somehow a long description.

I have a device that is essentially a [CAN Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) scanner. This device has a serial port, and upon receiving a Start command it starts mirroring whatever messages it captures on the CAN Bus until it receives a Stop command. The replied messages are wrapped in a variant of [PPP Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) to mitigate errors, given the fact that the serial port baud-rate is about 1MBaud.

I want to design a desktop application that connects to the scanner, sends commands to it, and receives the captured CAN messages. It should display the received messages in a ListBox/ListView, with the ability to live filter what is displayed by some criteria. It should also group by IDs embedded in each message, and display a list with encountered ID's and their total occurence. It should also display a total of distinct ID's, and a total count of messages.

What is received between a Start and a Stop command is a collection of messages that represent a record. The application should be capable to record multiple times in a session and must provide a way to persist records on disk along with applied filters, a user defined name, etc. The same application should be capable to import those records for offline analysis.

The fore mentioned ObjectThatConsumesXs is my record, that exposes it's contained messages as an Observable that reply to its subscribers(Reply operator).

I am using ReactiveUI - MVVM/WinForms/Reactive Extensions, and among others i have managed to design a service that exposes a `GetRecordUntil` function that returns an `IObservable(Of Record)`. Upon subscription the observable emits a single Record that is updated with messages received from the scanner.

I am opened to suggestion regarding the design of the application. But i am afraid that my question should be at least re-tagged if not even renamed.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would suggest a design that doesn't have you passing `IObservable(Of T)` in as parameters.
The Observable interfaces provide a way for something you depend on (i.e. has no knowledge of you) to call you back. 
However if you are passing an observable sequence to something, then you clearly know about it, and it clearly is expecting to be called (or react to ) stimulus. Why not just call methods on that dependency directly when the events happen?

Regardless, the current design you have will not pass on the `OnError`. 
The *outer* sequence you guarantee to only ever `OnNext` a single `ObjectThatConsumesXs` and then complete the sequence. 
Internally, that `ObjectThatConsumesXs` will subscribe to the published sequence, receive the error, but have no way to propagate that back to the other code path.

As another note, you have a type called `ObjectThatConsumesXs`, but you then go on to consumer the outer sequence directly  within the other method. 
Why the double handling?

If you can explain what it is that you are trying to do (not how you are trying to solve it), then I am sure the community can point you to a more appropriate design.

Comment: Thank you for your sugestions. I have edited my question to clarify what i'm trying to achive.